# Using if else for and del in the same line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, truncate

I have a list whose items are lists of variable lengths.

These list items of variable length need to be truncated to a specific length (x), if they exceed this length.

I have made this small function that does it.

```
def truncateList(batch_, trim_len):

truncated_list = []
for eachAbstract in train_abstracts_encoded:
    if len(eachAbstract) > trim_len:
        del eachAbstract[trim_len:]
        truncated_list.append(eachAbstract)
    else:
        truncated_list.append(eachAbstract)
return truncated_list
```

However, could I do it in a single line and in a more pythonic way?

like this:

```
prefData = [ del eachEncodedAbstract[MAX_LEN:] if len(eachEncodedAbstract) > 510 else eachEncodedAbstract for eachEncodedAbstract in test_abstracts_encoded]
```

But this did not work and I get en error.

```
    prefData = [ del eachEncodedAbstract[MAX_LEN:] if len(eachEncodedAbstract) > 510 else eachEncodedAbstract for eachEncodedAbstract in test_abstracts_encoded]
               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is already the most Pythonic way. Writing complicated (cryptic) comprehensions just because they fit a single line isn't best practice. One hint though: since `runcated_list.append(eachAbstract)` is common to the two `if/else` branches you can move it out and hence get rid of the `else` branch completely.

Comment: `del` is a statement - not an expression. You can't use a statement in a comprehension - only expressions

Comment: Why do you ``del eachAbstract[trim_len:]``? Why don't you just ``.append(eachAbstract[:trim_len])``?  Do you actually need the trimming to be visible for the original data?

Comment: "However, could I do it in a single line and in a more pythonic way?" single-line != pythonic. List comprehensions and related expressions (dict /set comprehensions and generator expressions) are meant for succinctly creating *mapping/filtering* operations. They are **not** meant to be "single-line for loops". Idiomatically, they should be functional transformations, i.e. free of side-effects, since these are functional programming constructs. `del` is an extremely imperative thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `eachEncodedAbstract[:MAX_LEN]`.

**Ex:**

```
prefData = [eachEncodedAbstract[:MAX_LEN] if len(eachEncodedAbstract) > 510 else eachEncodedAbstract for eachEncodedAbstract in test_abstracts_encoded]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the `eachAbstract` objects but just obtain a trimmed version then you can use the following:

```
truncated_list = [abstract[:trim_len] for abstract in train_abstracts_encoded]
```

Note that this is different from your version using `del` since it doesn't modify the object.

You can still simplify your version by moving the common  part out of the `if/else` branches:

```
truncated_list = []
for eachAbstract in train_abstracts_encoded:
    if len(eachAbstract) > trim_len:
        del eachAbstract[trim_len:]
    truncated_list.append(eachAbstract)
```

But since you're modifying objects in-place anyway you can just create a copy of the original list and then loop over it (this will be slightly faster because `copy()` avoids repeated calls to `append` and hence internal resizing):

```
truncated_list = train_abstracts_encoded.copy()
for eachAbstract in truncated_list:
    if len(eachAbstract) > trim_len:
        del eachAbstract[trim_len:]
```

Here `train_abstracts_encoded` and `truncated_list` share the same objects.